# Change Authentication mode from "Forms" to "Windows", but go to login.aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have changed the authentication mode from "Forms" to "Windows" and it looks something like this:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

The reason why I do this is to retrieve the current logged on user on IIS. But, everytime I debug my project, I always got this message:

```
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /login.aspx
```

I am not sure why it's asking to go to login.aspx
Can you help me please? thanks!

Comment: Somewhere in your code it's forwarding to login.aspx.  Look for that string in your codebase.

Comment: i have searched for it but found none

Comment: Maybe the project had login.aspx set as the Start Page?  Try setting a new aspx page as the start page.

Comment: just wondering, how do I know which page is set as the start page? thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a way of know what's set, just a way to change it.  Select the page you want to set as start, and right click, Set as Start Page.

Answer (score 0):

Check your IIS settings to make sure you have windows auth enabled, and disabled anonymous authentication.  Your config disables anonymous users, so if anonymous auth is enabled, it will be using the anonymous account to login with.

Comment: my Anonymous Authentication is disabled, both my ASP.net Impersonation and Windows Authentication are enabled

Answer (score 0):

If you started by selecting Internet Applications, then you need to remove the references to Webmatrix dlls from the project.